# exec doesn't work on window server 2008 php

Tags: php, windows, exec

i have a command below, if I run it through php file `http://localhost/myfile.php`

it will output the cmd but input_file.txt is not generated.

```
$cmd = "ffmpeg.exe -i C:\\ep-convert\\To_the_Beautiful_You_9.264 2> input_file.txt";
exec($cmd);
echo $cmd;
```

However if i copy the command output on the screen which is

```
ffmpeg.exe -i C:\ep-convert\To_the_Beautiful_You_9.264 2> input_file.txt
```

and i paste this in the console, its work.

The issue is if i run other exe file like mencoder or mplayer etc. the output is shown, however just specifically this ffmpeg.exe seems to not running with my exec()

what could have gone wrong and how to get exec work with the cmd above.

I am running window server 2008

Comment: Try adding a full path for ffmpeg.exe ?

Comment: i tried, but its seems cant take control of ffmpeg.exe , previously the code works. just suddenly it doesnt.

Comment: Windows is very finicky about permissions on allowing access to executables to the IIS user account.  You may need to check on whether the web server account has the correctly permission.  I would think you'd get an error though, maybe also check that you have php error reporting turned on temporarily so you can see if there is an actual error?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a file permissions problem. You may run this command from console just because you are running console as administrator. IIS has different user account. Accessing other files are restricted by default. You have to grant permission to that user for specific directories. You can simply right click folder then click properties. Go to the security tab and edit permissions.